# Xephyr Resolution Issue

Tags: ubuntu, xephyr

Whenever I try to connect to Ubuntu using [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr/), I always get it with the resolution set to 1600x1200, even though, I specified the switch `-screen 1024x768` when running it.

**Questions**

- Where is the issue?
- On server side or client side?

Unfortunately I don't have another server to test.

**NOTE:** If I connect to same server by using `Xnest` with any resolution then I do not face any problem

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I seem to have a similar issue....